# Ubuntu 20.04: WiFi hotspot not turning on saying system policy prohibits turning it on

Tags: wireless, network-manager, 20.04, hot-spot

[image: Turn on WiFi Hotspot option greyed out]

Ubuntu wifi hotspot is not turning on. It's saying system policy prohibits turning it on.

Comment: I just stumbled in the same problem. Did you manage to understand how to solve it? or did it just start working suddenly?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue as well, and the answer provided by [@niccco](https://askubuntu.com/a/1257668/1088059) to delete the connection did not help me.
After I set it all up, via commandline (https://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/connect-wifi-from-terminal-on-ubuntu-20-04/) and have it working, I change the wi-fi networks, and the option got greyed out again.
So, I was reading a [different article to setup a hotspot](https://tipsonubuntu.com/2020/05/10/wifi-hotspot-options-ubuntu-20-04/), and it mention in the very end, the following:

> In addition, “Turn on WiFi Hotspot” option randomly grayed out in my laptop, **switching tabs (left pane) in Settings and back** makes the option work again.

That was the answer that ultimately worked for me, without having to change anything anywhere, just accept that the GUI is flawed and have its quirks. After all, *change tabs* looks so silly...

Answer (score 1):

The following solution worked for me.

Run from terminal (or simply execute with `Alt` + `F2`) the command:

```
nm-connection-editor
```

In the window that opens up, search for the voice `hotspot` and delete it.

Then go back to the settings page and activate a new hotspot, maybe activating and deactivating flight mode for a couple of seconds before trying.

That solved the issue for me.